# Run migration with Pyinstaller

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy, pyinstaller, flask-migrate

I'm trying to run databases migration when the app is open.

I have create a runtime hooks `hook-runtime.py` with the following code

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate

from bridge.main import app, db

db = SQLAlchemy(app)
migrate = Migrate(app, db)

with app.app_context():
  from flask_migrate import upgrade as _upgrade
  _upgrade()
```

But I got the error: `Path doesn't exist 'migrations. Please use the 'init' command to create a new scripts folder`

My app.spec for PyInstaller:

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['app.py'],
             pathex=['<root_project_path>'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=['six', 'fractions', 'csv', 'pytz', 'timeit'],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=['hook-runtime.py'],
             excludes=['statsmodels'],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
a.datas += Tree("/wine/drive_c/Python36/Lib/site-packages/statsmodels", prefix="statsmodels")
a.datas += Tree("/wine/drive_c/Python36/Lib/site-packages/numpy", prefix="numpy")
a.datas += Tree("/wine/drive_c/Python36/Lib/site-packages/pandas", prefix="pandas")
a.datas += Tree("/wine/drive_c/Python36/Lib/site-packages/scipy", prefix="scipy")
a.datas += Tree("/wine/drive_c/Python36/Lib/site-packages/dateutil", prefix="dateutil")
a.datas += Tree("/wine/drive_c/Python36/Lib/site-packages/patsy", prefix="patsy")

pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          [],
          name='app',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=False,
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=True )
```

This is the project structure
[image]

This is the way to run the migrations with PyInstaller? If it is, what I'm doing wrong? If it isn't, how should I do it?

Comment: Is your migrations directory with all its contents included in your installer package?

Comment: The migrations folder is in the root of the project. I will edit my question with the structure

Comment: My question is if you are including these files in your installer. If you intend to run migrations then those files need to be available.

Comment: I'm still learning PyInstaller so I don't if the migration folder is being added, since I'm using `pyinstaller app.spec` to build. Should I add the migration folder on app.spec?

Comment: I don't use pyinstaller, but I can tell you that if you want to run a migration upgrade when you run the application then the entire contents of the migrations directory needs to be available.